# Neural Network unable to track training data

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, tensorflow, regression

I am new to ML and this is my first Tensorflow project. I am doing regression with Neural Networks on a dataset with 17 features and 1 outcome. But for some reason my network is unable to follow the training data. I am getting massive errors in results, as can be seen from the plots below. I have also tried experimenting with different parameters (learning rate, nodes per layer, number of layers etc) but nothing seems to work. 
I have pasted the Tensorflow code here. I have also provided my cost and training plots as well as a link to my datasets. I'd be grateful if someone could please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.
Thank you!

Links to the datasets-
Features arranged in columns-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U182Lhf67WygeSbv6BNEx5LHyL7Ba13O/view?usp=sharing
Output column -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10XWo1d5mhIsxccQBgAyGDWDAVgu2BjAA/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

# importing features and observations data for training and validation
training_filename_X = "training_set_X.csv"
training_filename_Y = "training_set_Y.csv"
validation_filename_X = "validation_set_X.csv"
test_filename_X = "test_set_X.csv"
test_filename_Y = "test_set_Y.csv"
validation_filename_Y = "validation_set_Y.csv"
training_features = np.loadtxt(training_filename_X, delimiter=',')
training_observations = np.loadtxt(training_filename_Y, delimiter=',')
validation_features = np.loadtxt(validation_filename_X, delimiter=',')
validation_observations = np.loadtxt(validation_filename_Y, delimiter=',')
test_features = np.loadtxt(test_filename_X, delimiter=',')
test_observations = np.loadtxt(test_filename_Y, delimiter=',')

# normalizing training data
training_features_stddev_arr = np.std(training_features, axis=0)
training_features_mean_arr = np.mean(training_features, axis=0)
normalized_training_features = (training_features-training_features_mean_arr)/training_features_stddev_arr

# layer parameters
n_nodes_hl1 = 5
n_nodes_hl2 = 5
n_nodes_hl3 = 3
no_features = 17
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 2000

cost_history = []

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# defining weights for each layer taken from a normal distribution with variance 2/n
hl1_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([no_features, n_nodes_hl1], stddev=np.sqrt(2/no_features)))
hl2_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2], stddev=np.sqrt(2/n_nodes_hl1)))
hl3_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3], stddev=np.sqrt(2/n_nodes_hl2)))
output_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, 1], stddev=np.sqrt(2/n_nodes_hl3)))

# defining biases for each layer
hl1_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_hl1], -1.0, 1.0))
hl2_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_hl2], -1.0, 1.0))
hl3_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_hl3], -1.0, 1.0))
output_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))

# defining activation functions for each layer
hl1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, hl1_weight) + hl1_bias)
hl2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hl1, hl2_weight) + hl2_bias)
hl3 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hl2, hl3_weight) + hl3_bias)
output = tf.matmul(hl3, output_weight) + output_bias

# using mean squared error cost function
cost  = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - Y))

# using Gradient Descent algorithm
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# running the network
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for step in np.arange(epochs):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:normalized_training_features, Y:training_observations})
#        print (sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:normalized_training_features, Y:training_observations}))
        cost_history.append(sess.run(cost,feed_dict={X:normalized_training_features, Y:training_observations}))

    pred_y = sess.run(output, feed_dict={X:normalized_training_features})

    plt.plot(range(len(cost_history)), cost_history)
```

Comment: Are they of the same scale? Also change your hidden layer neurons, your LR by *10 and epoch/10.. and report back..

Comment: @Aditya I changed the LR and epoch (LR = 0.01, epoch = 200) as you suggested in the above code. It still gives the same plots for prediction.

Comment: @Aditya Also if you look at the data (google drive link provided), the features are of different scales but I have done feature scaling (normalizing training data) in the above code. Please let me know if the procedure I followed for normalization is not correct. Thanks!

Comment: Why in the world are you using squred error cost for sigmoid activation?

Comment: @DuttaA Sorry, I am very new to the field of ML and my concepts aren't great right now. I thought the two could be used together. Also something similar was suggested here - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229140/choosing-from-different-cost-function-and-activation-function-of-a-neural-networ
Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: why dont you change your tf.square to cross entropy...here is the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

Comment: @DuttaA Cross entropy for regression?

Comment: @Aditya missed it, but still I doubt whether squared error is the correct function.... Because it is still sigmoid * w in the last layer

Comment: i had ran the code with relu, its weird that its predicting nearly constant predictions as if its not learning anything bu the cost is going down, couldn't find the bug as i don't use tf

Comment: @user53799 Can you see the visuals in the tensorboard as to what is going wrong(chack the connectivity and weights and all), my best guess is the network isn't learning probably

Comment: Have you tried to implement a standard (generalized) linear regression model to check whether what you want your Network to detect is valid at all? Possible problems in the data might be detectable there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found out atleast one thing why it's happening that way after asking my friends,

We can't use sigmoid as the last layer since it will always output something between 0 and 1 and hence that's why your predictions are not varying at all...
i.e we can't at all use sigmoid as the last layer until it's a classification of let's say images and all...

Comment: Are you sure? Because he is multiplying it with a W

Comment: Yes it's Mathematically sound, since you will be multiplying something with less than 1 for sure, you will obviously decrease it's value

Comment: @Aditya Thank you so much for your feedback. I tried the same code with 1 hidden layer on housing price dataset. That seems to be working fine. I did not know how to post the code and the plot in comment so here are the links-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmlrfzdKJCBdD_Ub5_L_rn50GHMRPynf/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKHerBgLzLt4Bhbf7jIEaIDQNCsSgyO4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DuttaAThank you so much for your feedback. I tried the same code with 1 hidden layer on housing price dataset. That seems to be working fine. I did not know how to post the code and the plot in comment so here are the links-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmlrfzdKJCBdD_Ub5_L_rn50GHMRPynf/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKHerBgLzLt4Bhbf7jIEaIDQNCsSgyO4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @alex2006 Thank you so much for your feedback. I tried the same code with 1 hidden layer on housing price dataset. That seems to be working fine. I did not know how to post the code and the plot in comment so here are the links-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmlrfzdKJCBdD_Ub5_L_rn50GHMRPynf/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKHerBgLzLt4Bhbf7jIEaIDQNCsSgyO4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Aditya If I cannot use sigmoid in the last layer should I use Relu instead? Thanks!

Comment: The housing dataset is also in the code (links above). Thanks!